# nginx + tomcat reverse proxy trouble

Tags: tomcat, nginx, centos

So I am having trouble setting up nginx with tomcat and, while there are many bits of help out there, I haven't found anything that I recognize as quite applying to my situation.  Since this is not part of my normal skillset, I might just be missing some key words or concept.

Right now I am just trying to get Tomcat's default landing page to work.  CentOS  7.5.1804 with yum installed versions of nginx (1:1.12.2-2.el7) and tomcat (7.0.76-6.el7) alongside several other services.

My config file looks something like:

```
    server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate "stuff";
    ssl_certificate_key "stuff";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location /other/ {
  rewrite ^/other/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost:1234/ $scheme://$host/1234/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_read_timeout 20d;
}

location /tomcat/ {
    rewrite ^/tomcat/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

When I go to my server:

https://example.com/tomcat

The landing page loads fine.  However if I mouse over the links like documentation or examples I get links like:

https://example.com/docs
https://example.com/example

If I manually enter "https://example.com/tomcat/examples/" it loads fine, though any link below that produces a correct mouseover (such as https://example.com/tomcat/examples/servlets) that due to missing the trailing / results in nginx rewriting it as "https://example.com/examples/servlets/".

So I am missing something.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.